# Matplotlib don't show all ticks/labels with bar chart. It skips first of y axis and last one of x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Matplotlib don't show all ticks/labels with bar chart. It skips first of y axis and last one of x axis.

```
figsize = plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
axes1 = plt.subplot(2,2,1,title = "Scatter plot with Upper Traingle Markers")
axes1.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
axes1.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
axes1.set_xlim(0,1.2)
axes1.set_ylim(-0.2,1.0)
axes2 = plt.subplot(2,2,2,title = "Scatter plot with Plus Markers")
axes2.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
axes2.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
axes3 = plt.subplot(2,2,3,title = "Scatter plot with Circle Markers")
axes3.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
axes3.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
axes4 = plt.subplot(2,2,4,title = "Scatter plot with Diamond Markers")
axes4.set_xticks([0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2])
axes4.set_yticks([-0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0])
np.random.seed(1000)
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
z = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
axes1.scatter(x,y, s = 80,c =z,marker = "^")
axes2.scatter(x,y, s = 80,c =z,marker = "+")
axes3.scatter(x,y, s = 80,c =z,marker = "o")
axes4.scatter(x,y, s = 80,c =z,marker = "d")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("x.png")
```

Expected plot
[image]

My plot

[image]

. Starts at zero and zero. If I don't use the lim functions the graph start at the same point as expected plot.

If the graph images won't match, My test cases wont pass. Can you help me with this

Comment: `axes1.set_xlim(0, 1.3); axes2.set_ylim(-0.3, 1.1)` works as expected. I think you misunderstand the [differences between pyplot and object oriented axis programming](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

Comment: please check now. I have attached images now.  If u use the lim functions the graph starts at 0,0. please check images for better understanding. Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The general point is that Matplotlib will not expand the limits of your plot area to accommodate the limits of your axis ticks. Autoscaling only applies to the data points. You should choose limits that make sense for your data; Mr. T was guessing at what those limits should be.

Comment: Neither plot corresponds to [your code output](https://imgur.com/iuF3dqJ) as you relabeled the x-axis with `axes1.set_xticklabels(['two', 'four','six', 'eight'])`. Please include the entire code that generates your undesired output.

Comment: Fixed it. axes1.set_xticklabels(['two', 'four','six', 'eight']) was just a diagnosing step.

Comment: Please check where the 0 in  x axis begins in my plot(when i use lim function) and expected plot

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib will not automatically expand your axis limits to in response to changing the axis ticks. Autoscaling only applies to plotted data points.

If the automatic limits are not suitable for you, then you need to use the `ax.set_xlim` and/or `.set_ylim` methods to manually X and/or Y limits.

Comment: If i use the lim function the output is shown in fig - myplot. But i want it as in expected plot. the 0 in x axis differ. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: And y -1.0 ends on the line. it doesn't happen in expected plot. i want the graph to be exact to pass my test case.

Comment: @Varun it sounds like you just need to set different limits.